# Layer-Backed NSControl Still Calls NSCell Drawing Routines

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, calayer, appkit, nscontrol

## Context:

Apple has "soft-deprecated" NSCell on macOS. I'm trying to reduce the use of it in my custom NSControl subclasses and, instead, use CALayers to handle my drawing. To do this, I make my NSButton subclass layer-backed:

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
```

And then I attempt to handle my drawing using the "updateLayer" path instead of "drawRect":

```
- (BOOL) wantsUpdateLayer {
    return YES;
}

- (void) updateLayer { 
     // Change layer background/border colors if pressed, disabled, etc.
     // Change text color of a CATextLayer sublayer for button's title. 
}
```

---

## The Problem:

If I use `-updateLayer`, the NSCell still receives drawing commands and draws its title, resulting in a "blurry" title string in my control because the string is being drawn twice—once in my textLayer and once by the Cell.

If, however, I do the exact same work as above in `-drawRect:` instead of `-updateLayer`, then the cell does NOT do any drawing (because I don't call down into it with `[self.cell drawInteriorWithFrame:ControlView:]`)

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what's firing the cell drawing when the associated controlView (my button subclass) has opted into `-updateLayer` instead of `-drawRect:`.

I have looked at all the methods on NSControl.h and NSView.h. I've overridden all of the `-updateCell` and associated methods. None of those are the culprit. I cannot simply set `self.cell=nil` because NSControl still relies on NSCell for event handling, etc.

Can someone tell me how to stop NSCell from drawing when its associated controlView is using `-updateLayer` instead of `-drawRect:`?

Comment: In `-[NSButtonCell layoutLayerWithFrame:inView:]`, the cell adds a `NSTextField` to draw the title. Override `titleRectForBounds:` and return `NSZeroRect` to remove the title.

Comment: That does indeed work. Move it to an official answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `-[NSButtonCell layoutLayerWithFrame:inView:]`, the cell adds a `NSTextField` to draw the title. Override `titleRectForBounds:` and return `NSZeroRect` to remove the title.